# ansible conditionals based on list item match

Tags: ansible

I could not find a suitable way to confirm and conditionalize if a list contains a item:

```
var = "{{
  item1
+ item2
+ item3
}}"
```

ansible:

```
- hosts: all*
  tags: always
  tasks:

  - name: conditional
    file:
      state: directory
      path: /etc/temp
      owner: mike
      group: mike
      mode: 0750
    when: "'item3' in {{ var }}"
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var = "{{
  item1
+ item2
+ item3
}}"
```

The above seems a string not a list, so it won't working with `in` instead you've to use `==` for this to work or create a proper list in ansible with

```
with_items:
  - item 1
  - item 2
  - item 3
```

or if you are looking for **a string contains way**(for strings not lists), then do like this

```
when: var.find("logstash_config_filter_roletype_validation") != -1
```

Comment: I already tried it but get this error `'list object' has no attribute 'find'`

Comment: That's where I got stuck. And ansible documentation doesn't seem to cover details of use cases in this sense

Comment: you cannot do 'find' on list it's string property, if you are making a string go with that @S1c0r4x

Comment: But how? I was thinking to try `when: "'item3' in '{{var.stdout}}'"` or `{{var}}` I am not sure how ansible interprets objects when parsing them. If there should be just variable after constructor or with stdout .. in the when condition`

Answer (score 0):

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  vars:
       list_containing_item:
          - item1
          - item2
          - item3

  tasks:
        - name: make directory
          file:
            state: directory
            path: /tmp/demo
            owner: root
            group: root
            mode: 0750
          when: "'item3' in list_containing_item"
```

This is working fine for me. You do not need {{}} in when conditions. 
Refer this: [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)